# Casting non-numeric char to int?

Tags: c#

I came across this line of code today:

`int c = (int)'c';`

I was not aware you could cast a `char` to an `int`. So I tested it out, and found that a=97, b=98, c=99, d=100 etc etc...

Why is 'a' 97? What do those numbers relate to?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/ascii-table

Comment: Read this before you write another line of code: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I got a job as a software developer without ever having written any (proper) code. I've gotta learn on the job! :)

Comment: Technically, that is an explicit cast (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105(v=vs.80).aspx)... just to be nitpicky...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Everyone else (so far) has referred to ASCII. That's a very limited view - it works for `'a'`, but doesn't work for anything with an accent etc - which can very easily be represented by `char`.

A `char` is just an unsigned 16-bit integer, which is a [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) *code unit*. *Usually* that's equivalent to a Unicode character, but not always - sometimes multiple code units are required for a single full character. See the documentation for [`System.Char`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.aspx) for more details.

The implicit conversion from `char` to `int` (you don't need the cast in your code) just converts that 16-bit unsigned integer to a 32-bit signed integer in the natural, non-lossy way - just as if you had a `ushort`.

Note that every valid character in ASCII has the same value in UTF-16, which is why the two are often confused when the examples are only ones from the ASCII set.

Comment: When a simple "it's ascii" is insufficient, leave it to Jon Skeet to get in to the etiology.

Comment: Well, I think this is the only **full** (and 100% correct) answer, it certainly deserves more upvotes.

Comment: This wasn't the first answer, but as usual it is the most informative!

Answer (score 7):

`97` is UTF-16 code unit value of letter `a`.

Basically this number relates to UTF-16 code unit of given character.

Comment: [asciitable.com](http://www.asciitable.com) for quick reference (see the **dec** column).

Comment: Technically correct, but `char` is a UTF-16 code unit, not an ascii character.

Answer (score -1):

These are the [ASCII values representing the characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Answer (score -1):

They are character codes, commonly known as ASCII values.

Technically, though, the character codes are not ASCII.

Comment: They're UTF-16 code units. *Not* the same as UTF-8. It's not clear where VS comes in here, either... it's part of the language and the platform, regardless of which IDE you use.

Comment: Well, hence the "I believe"... the pertinent point was that they were actually character codes that coincide with ASCII, but are not actually ASCII.

Comment: New downvoter care to comment?  The answer is factually accurate.

Comment: Calling UTF-16 ascii is like calling an 18-wheeler a car.  They're both road vehicles (character codes) but while they're interchangable for some jobs, you're asking for trouble if you always treat them the same.

Comment: @RoadieRich, please read my answer again.  I called them character codes.  One needs only look at this list of answers calling them ASCII codes to see that people commonly refer to them as ASCII values, but they aren't.  Also like I noted.

Comment: You did, but I don't think that is a helpful thing to perpetuate. People commonly used to think the sun orbited the earth - just because it's common, doesn't mean it's correct.  At least **that** didn't risk causing bugs in common software.

Comment: ...I think you're being a bit trigger-happy with the downvote, but whatever.

Answer (score -1):

They are the decimal representation of their ascii counterpart:
http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif
so 'a' would be a 97

Comment: [Not ascii, utf-16.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/x9h8tsay.aspx)