# Casting ((char) a) where a is any number between int range

Tags: java, character-encoding, casting, ascii, cjk

I know that ASCII codes are between 0-127 in decimal and `0000 0000` to `0111 1111` in binary, and that values between 128-255 are extended ASCII.

I also know that int accepts 9 digits(which I was wrong the range `int` is between(-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647)), so if we cast every number between (0-Max`int`Range)  to a `char`, there will be many many symbols; for example:

`(char)999,999,999` gives 짿 which is a *Korean* symbol (I don't know what it even means; Google Translate can't find any meaning!).

The same thing happens with values between min`int`range to 0.

It doesn't make sense that those symbols were input one by one.

I don't understand - how could they assign those big numbers to have its own character?

Comment: You might want to check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906273/casting-non-numeric-char-to-int/15906311#15906311

Comment: Chars in C# are characters in the Unicode UTF-16 encoding. You should read this article and then come back if you have more questions: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @EricLippert: But it does raise the question, why would a cast like that succeed with some more or less pseudo-random result, rather than overflowing, throwing an exception or doing something similarly sensible?

Comment: What's the actual question? Why you don't understand is hard to answer. Would you mind rephrasing the question? Who are "they" in your last question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, because explicit casts don't cause overflow by default? `checked` is not the default...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Sounds like a reasonable answer to the OP's question, if the Korean character result can be explained.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: There are two meanings for a cast, either "I know that this expression is actually of this other type; throw an exception if I'm wrong".  Or it means "I know that this expression is not of this other type but there is a corresponding value in that other type; give me the corresponding value". That these two meanings are opposites is a nice trick, isn't it?

Comment: That *is* a nice trick.

Comment: The range of a int is [`Int32.MinValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.minvalue.aspx) (-2,147,483,648) to [`Int32.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx) (2,147,483,647)

Comment: Thank you all for the very useful comments.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I don't understand how they assign those big numbers to have it's own symbol?

The assignments are made by the Unicode consortium. See http://unicode.org for details.

In your particular case however you are doing something completely nonsensical. You have the integer 999999999 which in hex is 0x3B9AC9FF. You then cast that to char, which discards the top four bytes and gives you 0xC9FF. If you then look that up at Unicode.org: http://www.unicode.org/cgi-bin/Code2Chart.pl and discover that yes, it is a Korean character.

Unicode code points can in fact be quite large; there are over a million of them. But you can't get to them just by casting. To get to Unicode code points that are outside of the "normal" range using UTF-16 (as C# does), you need to use *two* characters. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16, the section on surrogate pairs.

To address some of the other concerns in your question:

> I know that ACCII codes are between (0-127) in decimal and (0000 0000 to 0000 1111) in binary.

That's **ASCII**, not **ACCII**, and 127 in binary is 01111111, not 00001111

> Also we know that int accepts 9 digits, so if we cast every number between

The range of an int is larger than that.

> don't know what it mean even Google translate can't find any meaning

Korean is not like Chinese, where each glyph represents a word. Those are *letters*. They don't have a meaning unless they happen to accidentally form a word. You'd have about as much luck googling randomly chosen English letters and trying to find their meaning; maybe sometimes you'd choose CAT at random, but most of the time you'd choose XRO or some such thing that is not a word.

Read this if you want to understand how the Korean alphabet works: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangul

Comment: Thanks, the answer were more than I expected. in java `int` is 9 digit,isn't ?

Comment: @AzadOmer: It is not. It's 32 bits, same as in C#. And you're welcome!

Comment: @AzadOmer: If you are interested in learning more than any human ought to know about Unicode, Michael Kaplan is one of the world's leading experts and he writes a blog about it: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/

Comment: I will certainly read it it's one of my big interests. by the way nice number 222k.